# Problems with NSFetchedResultsController in iOS7?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` to load some data into `UITableView`. No matter how many objects I save, it only loads the first one. If I delete that one object from the `UITableView` and reload it, sometimes it will show one or more of the other objects I've saved. It's very unpredictable.

The strange thing is the code I was using worked fine on the iOS6 SDK. I know that the issue is with the `NSFetchedResultsController` because when I make a fetch request with NSFetchRequest, the data that is returned is correct. Here is the code;

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSError *error;

    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
    {
        exit(-1);
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
}

    - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
    {
        if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
        {
            return _fetchedResultsController;
        }

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"HatInfo" inManagedObjectContext:[self.appDelegate managedObjectContext]];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastSaved" ascending:NO];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:9];
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self.appDelegate managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
        //returns the correct amount of objects
        NSLog(@"FetchedObjects: %lu", (unsigned long)[fetchedObjects count]);

        NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
        [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                            managedObjectContext:[self.appDelegate managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                       cacheName:@"Root"];
        self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
        _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

        return _fetchedResultsController;

    }

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id  sectionInfo = [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    //returns the incorrect amount
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are not using the @"Root" cache for other fetchedResultsController in other parts of your app?

Comment: I'm not really sure, that was just copied code from Ray Wenderlich. I actually set the cache to nil and now it works. Do you want to put that as an answer? And do you know if I'm setting the cache to nil, am I just completely losing the benefits of the fetchedresultscontroller? @LombaX

Comment: Added as an answer. Instead of changing it to nil, simply change the cache name from @"Root" to something else, for example @"HatInfoFetchedResultsControllerCache"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of unexpected behavior can happen if you used the same `cacheName` in other part of core data code (for example: another `fetchedResultsController` in your app.
You can try to change the cache name to something different or nil and see what happens.

Comment: Tried changing it to some arbitrary random name and still got the buggy effects. Nil is what ended up working in the end for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before you start fetch :

```
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:<< catch name>>];
```